# When extracting artist name from XML file only 1 record shows

Tags: php, xml

I have searched on stack but no question or answer answers this question directly as far as I can tell.

I have this code below:

```
$xml_data = file_get_contents('http://www.test.co.uk/charts.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_data);

$artist = $xml->artists->artist->name;
echo $artist;
```

However when I run this code it only shows the first artist name, does any one know how I could get it to show all of the names in the xml file.

For your reference the xml file is laid out as follows:

```
<artists_chart start="" end="">
<period>Past 7 days</period>
<artists>
<artist gid="">
<name>Name1</name>
<plays>51</plays>
<previous_plays>53</previous_plays>
</artist>
<artist gid="">
<name>Name2</name>
<plays>45</plays>
<previous_plays>97</previous_plays>
</artist>
<artist gid="">
<name>Name3</name>
<plays>41</plays>
<previous_plays>39</previous_plays>
</artist>
</artists>
</artists_chart>
```

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: You are looking for `foreach`

Comment: @gordon i tried a foreach but it still only registers 1 record

Comment: `foreach(simplexml_load_file('http://…')->artists->artist as $artist) {
    echo $artist->name;
}`

Comment: @Gordon - this displays a server error

Comment: then you are doing something else wrong. If that URL hosts the XML shown above, the snippet I gave you will echo all the artists names. See http://codepad.org/c0ZL1hLZ

Comment: The issue is that http://www.test.co.uk/ is configured to use 127.0.0.1 as the remote IP (somehow).  I noticed when I visit the site directly it shows me a listing of my local WAMP instead of whats on that box.  If you try to open a browser and go to http://www.test.co.uk/charts.xml it will just give you a listing of your local web server.  Kinda funny, but not really.

Comment: FOund it, in source for index.html on that site:
<FRAME NAME="main" SRC="http://127.0.0.1" FRAMEBORDER="0" SCROLLING="AUTO">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($xml->artists->children() as $child)
{
  $artist = (string)$child->name;
  echo $artist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use xpath to select the nodes (artists/artist) and then iterate the result set.  XPath and PHP is covered quite well at http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

In specific to your question though:

```
$xml_data = file_get_contents('http://www.test.co.uk/charts.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_data);

$artists = $xml->xpath('/artists/artist');
if($artists) foreach($artsts as $artist){
  echo $artist->name;
}
```

EDIT with Updated Code:

```
<?php

$xml_data = <<<XML
<artists_chart start="" end="">
  <period>Past 7 days</period>
  <artists>
    <artist gid="">
      <name>Name1</name>
      <plays>51</plays>
      <previous_plays>53</previous_plays>
    </artist>
    <artist gid="">
      <name>Name2</name>
      <plays>45</plays>
      <previous_plays>97</previous_plays>
    </artist>
    <artist gid="">
      <name>Name3</name>
      <plays>41</plays>
      <previous_plays>39</previous_plays>
    </artist>
  </artists>
</artists_chart>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_data);

$artists = $xml->xpath('/artists_chart/artists/artist');
if($artists) foreach($artists as $artist){
  echo $artist->name.'<br />';
}
echo('<hr />');
// or
foreach($xml->artists->artist as $artist){
  echo $artist->name.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Sorry bit more detail and working examples using and not using xpath:

Answer (score 0):

add to your code to looks like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$xml_data = file_get_contents('http://www.test.co.uk/charts.xml');
....
```

and you will see:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 6: parser error : Entity 'copy' not defined in 
.......
```

**EDIT 1**

sorry this error only mean that 'access forbidden'.
but if i copy your xml as text - all works for me (and displays `Name1`).

Comment: thanks for your help, I want it to display all of the names so Name1 Name2 and Name3